# How to set size radius circles inversely proportionally to zoom level in Shiny Leaflet?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Leaflet use zoom levels from 0 (world) to 18 (local).

In my map, circles shapes are set with 5000 meters radius at max scale (zoom level: 18).

How can I increase the radius of my circles shapes inversely proportionally to zoom level input.

What I want : bigger circles at world zoom level (ex: 100 000 meters, radius x10) and decrease to 5000 (zoom  level 18)

How to set  size of circles  inversely proportionally to zoom level

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

df <- data.frame(
  location_name = c('S1', 'S2'),
  lng = c(-1.554136,  -2.10401),
  lat = c(47.218637, 47.218637), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    leafletOutput(outputId = 'map')
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles()
  })

  observeEvent(
    eventExpr = input$map_zoom, {
      print(input$map_zoom)           # Display zoom level in the console
      leafletProxy(
        mapId = "map", 
        session = session
      ) %>% 
        clearShapes() %>%
        addCircles(
          data = df, 
          lng = ~lng,
          lat = ~lat,
          radius = ~ 5000 * 1/input$map_zoom # increase too slightly
        )
    }
  )


})

shinyApp(
  ui = ui, 
  server = server
)
```

I don't want to use `addCircleMarkers` function

Comment: are you sure about `ex: 100 000 meters, radius x10) and decrease to 5000 (zoom level 18)`. This cold be calculated: `f(zoom) = constant + zoom*x; 100000 = constant + 10*x;5000 = constant + 18*x;  Solving this leads to: `218750 -11875*zoom` (assuming the size should decrease linearly, otherwise take another function,...)

Comment: @BigDataScientist Thank you for helping. I want to display my circles from local (500m zoom levle 18 to global (zoom level 0) so to display my circles I need to change their radius to kilometers

Comment: @BigDataScientist  Can you post a  reproductible answer ?